# get reddit comments with jquery & json

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

Can anyone tell me why:

**getting reddit posts**: http://jsfiddle.net/U7Wv6/2/ this works

**getting reddit comments**: http://jsfiddle.net/U7Wv6/7/ and this doesn't?

The json output format looks pretty similar. I'm so stumped. any help is appreciated... I'm just trying to get the first/top 10 comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works http://jsfiddle.net/U7Wv6/8/
The comments return an array of objects so you need to select the first element in the array

```
 results[0].data
```